# Samsung Galaxy A22 5G never shows 5G

Tags: samsung, mobile-network

My 'Samsung Galaxy A22 5G' never shows "5G" on its status bar, despite being where 5G coverage is proven (checked on another 5G smartphone of mine).

It only shows "4G+".

https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a22_5g-10873.php lists this phone as having 5G bands: `1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 20, 28, 38, 40, 41, 78, 79 SA/NSA/Sub6`

Entering my phone's IEMI into https://www.imei.info only shows the following: `IMEI.info: LTE-FDD: 800, 900, 2100, 2600` and `IMEI.info: LTE-TDD: 2300, 2500, 2600`:

[image: Samsung Galaxy A22 5G IEMI info]

I verified that its 'Network mode' is set to `5G/LTE/3G/2G (auto connect)`.

I also tried resetting its network settings via `General management` > `Reset` > `Reset network settings`.

Still, it only shows `4G+`. It never shows `5G`.

Any idea why?

Comment: What bands are used for 5g by your network provider? It may be also relevant if your network provider uses 5g standalone or non-standalone. The latter uses 5g just as speed enhancement for 4g.

Comment: @Robert 700MHz, 2.6GHz, 3.5GHz

Comment: You need to buy a phone that is meant for your country. You cant just buy one at random from ebay and be certain that it will work in your country or with your provider. They are built with different antennae and firmware.

Comment: @RohitGupta I actually bought it brand new in a reputable local store in my country.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided so far, it looks like your 5G phone (800MHz, 900MHz, 2.1GHz, 2.3GHZ, 2.5GHz, 2.6GHz) is incompatible with your network provider's 5G (700MHz, 2.6GHz, 3.5GHz).

In general:

| LTE-FDD | LTE-TDD | 5G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 700 MHz (B12, B13, B14, B17), 850 MHz (B5), 1800 MHz (B3), 1900 MHz (B2), 2100 MHz (B1), 2600 MHz (B7) | 2300 MHz (B40), 2500 MHz (B41), 2600 MHz (B38, B39) | Sub-6 GHz bands (e.g., 600 MHz, 2.5 GHz, 3.5 GHz), mmWave bands (e.g., 28 GHz, 39 GHz) |

In other words:

| Your Phone's LTE | Your Network's Provider 5G |
| --- | --- |
| 800MHz, 900MHz, 2.1GHz, 2.3GHZ, 2.5GHz, 2.6GHz | 700MHz, 2.6GHz, 3.5GHz |

The only common frequency is 2.6GHz, but on your phone it is listed under LTE, so it looks like this is the reason it only displays `4G+` .